# MongoDB replica set in Azure "Waiting for role to start... Calling OnRoleStart()"

Tags: mongodb, azure

I have a problem trying to implement a mongodb replica set as a worker role instance in Windows Azure. In the Windows Azure portal, one of the instances is shown as busy with the status:

```
Waiting for role to start... Calling OnRoleStart()
```

I have checked all the settings and everything seems to be ok, what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Denis Markelov's](http://www.denismarkelov.com/2012/09/mongodb-replica-set-in-windows-azure.html) blog post helped me solve this problem. The solution is mainly his, however I had to take an extra step to get it to work and thought others might find it useful.

Solution from blog:

> Windows Azure reuses virtual machines for roles, so after a fresh
>   deployment on a hard drive you can find files that were created during
>   previous sessions. If MongoDB was terminated improperly - there might
>   be a lock file ("persisted mutex" analogue), because of which MongoDB
>   refuses to start. It is located at the drive with a label
>   "WindowsAzureDrive" (say it is F:), at the path:
>
> F:\data\mongod.lock
>
> In the case of a production use this situation might require a
>   recovery procedures, **but if you are just in the process of initial
>   setup - it is safe to remove this file, letting MongoDB to start
>   again.**

I was having this problem and did as suggested, however I was still having the same problem. So I took a look at the log file at

> C:\Resources\Directory\.MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole.MongodLogDir\mongod.txt

And saw that another file was also giving an error. In order to fix the problem, you also have to delete the file `local.ns` in the same directory as `mongod.lock`.